# Avoiding Data Duplication when Loading Data from Multiple Servers

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a dozen web servers each writing data to a log file. At the beginning of each hour, the data from the previous hour is loaded to hive using a cron script running the command:

```
hive -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'myfile.log' INTO TABLE my_table PARTITION(dt='2015-08-17-05')"
```

In some cases, the command fails and exits with a code other than 0, in which case our script awaits and tries again. The problem is, in some cases of failure, the data loading does *not* fail, even though it shows a failure message. How can I know for sure whether or not the data has been loaded?

Example for such a "failure" where the data *is* loaded:

> Loading data to table default.my_table partition (dt=2015-08-17-05)
>   Failed with exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to alter
>   partition. FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

**Edit:**
Alternatively, is there a way to query hive for the filenames loaded into it? I can use `DESCRIBE` to see the number of files. Can I know their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About "which files have been loaded in a partition":

- if you had used an `EXTERNAL TABLE` and just uploaded your raw data
  file in the HDFS directory mapped to `LOCATION`, then you could

(a) just run a `hdfs dfs -ls` on that directory from command line (or use the equivalent Java API call)
(b) run a Hive query such as `select distinct INPUT__FILE__NAME from (...)`

- but in your case, you copy the data into a "managed" table, so there
  is no way to retrieve the data lineage (i.e. which log file was used
  to create each managed datafile)
- ...unless you add *explicitly* the original file name *inside* the log file, of
  course (either on "special" header record, or at the beginning of each record - which can be done with good old `sed`)

---

About "how to automagically avoid duplication on INSERT": there is a way, but it would require quite a bit of re-engineering, and would cost you in terms of processing time /(extra Map step plus MapJoin)/...

1. map your log file to an `EXTERNAL TABLE` so that you can run an
   INSERT-SELECT query
2. upload the original file name into your managed table using `INPUT__FILE__NAME` pseudo-column as source
3. add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause w/ correlated sub-query, so that if the source file name is already present in target then you load nothing more

   `INSERT INTO TABLE Target
   SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, INPUT__FILE__NAME AS SrcFileName
   FROM Source src
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT DISTINCT 1
     FROM Target trg
     WHERE trg.SrcFileName =src.INPUT__FILE__NAME
    )`

   *Note the silly DISTINCT that is actually required to avoid blowing away the RAM in your Mappers; it would be useless with a mature DBMS like Oracle, but the Hive optimizer is still rather crude...*

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can simply do this is in Hadoop/Hive.  So here are the basics of an implementation in python:

```
import subprocess
x=subprocess.check_output([hive -e "select count(*) from my_table where dt='2015-08-17-05'"])
print type(x)
print x
```

But you have to spend some time working with backslashes to get hive -e to work using python.  It can be very difficult.  It may be easier to write a file with that simple query in it first, and then use `hive -f filename`. Then, print the output of `subprocess.check_output` in order to see how the output is stored.   You may need to do some regex or type conversions, but I think it should just come back as a string. Then simply use an if statement:

```
if x > 0:
    pass
else:
    hive -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'myfile.log' INTO TABLE my_table PARTITION(dt='2015-08-17-05')"
```

Comment: My problem is that the error code does not reflect the result of the loading. In the above example, the loading succeeds - the data is present in the hive table - and still an error code 1 is returned.

Comment: The above code queries the table to see if anything was successfully inserted.  If something was inserted into the table, then it does not run the LOAD.  If that hourly partition is empty, then it loads the partition.

Comment: Right, sorry, I misunderstood. But still, I have many simultaneous insertions to the same partition, so it not being empty does not necessarily mean a success.

Comment: Is the error for a failed entry identical to the error for an entry that succeeds but outputs an error?

Comment: No, it's not the same error. So I could check for this specific error type. However, my question is whether there is a general way to know whether or not the loading succeeded, without having to parse the error message.